# How to split a combination of numeric and characters into multiple columns

Tags: sas

I want to split some variable "15to16" into two columns where for that row I want the values 15 and 16 in each of the column entries. Hence, I want to get from this

```
+-------------+
|   change    |   
+-------------+
| 15to16      | 
| 9to8        | 
| 6to5        | 
| 10to16      | 
+-------------+
```

this

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|   change    |   from    |   to      |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| 15to16      | 15        |     16    |
| 9to8        | 9         |     8     |
| 6to5        | 6         |     5     |
| 10to16      | 10        |     16    |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data have;
input change $;
cards;
15to16
9to8
6to5
10to16
;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  from = input(scan(change,1,'to'), 8.);
  to = input(scan(change,2,'to'), 8.);
run;
```

N.B. in this case the `scan` function is using both `t` and `o` as separate delimiters, rather than looking for the word `to`. This approach still works because `scan` by default treats multiple consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter.

Comment: You could also `scan(tranwrd(change,'to',' '),1)` and `scan(tranwrd(change,'to',' '),2)`

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions with the metacharacter `()` define groups whose contents can be retrieved from capture buffers with `PRXPOSN`.  The capture buffers retrieved in this case would be one or more consecutive decimals `(\d+)` and converted to a numeric value with `INPUT`

```
data have;
input change $20.; datalines;
15to16
9to8  
6to5  
10to16
run;

data want;
  set have;

  rx = prxparse('/^\s*(\d+)\s*to\s*(\d+)\s*$/');

  if prxmatch (rx, change) then do;
    from = input(prxposn(rx,1,change), 12.);
    to   = input(prxposn(rx,2,change), 12.);
  end;

  drop rx;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer you want by declaring delimiter when you create the dataset. However you did not provide enough information regarding your other variables and how you import them

```
Data want;
INFILE datalines DELIMITER='to';
INPUT from to;
datalines; 
15to16
9to8
6to5
10to16
;
Run;
```